# Unable to find package location when creating application using yfiles-application generator

Tags: yfiles

I am using the below documentation to get started with yfiles application.
https://github.com/yWorks/generator-yfiles-app

I am stuck with the 2nd question the generator asks "Path of yFiles for HTML package".

What is the default location of this package? Is this a package.json file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved the issue.

No where in the documentation/read-me did it mention that I had to download the package separately.

https://www.yworks.com/downloads

I had to download and unzip the contents. And this directory becomes the location of the package.

Comment: The readme states the following at the very top: *»A yeoman generator that scaffolds a [yFiles for HTML](https://www.yworks.com/yfileshtml) powered application. Requires a local yFiles for HTML package which can be [obtained and evaluated here](https://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles-for-html/evaluate).«*